# create civiVolunteer not work

Tags: civivolunteer

civicrm 5.69 drupal 10.2.2

i installed civicrm ,  have 1 plugin civivolunteer, i try go to create page , can not show create form, TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'entityTable') ,i am not sure is db error or js error , i try to find (civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.angularprofiles/js/crmProfiles.js).

if i hidden var scripts = [ ...], or loadNextScript(scripts, function () {
window.jQuery = CRM.origJQuery;
delete CRM.origJQuery;
delete window._;
deferred.resolve(true);
}, function(status) {
deferred.resolve(status);
});

will no any data in page,i spend many time to solve problem, but dont how to fixed, please help me.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Last I heard from the CiviVolunteer extension authors, they said that the extension is not needed by most orgainzations because tracking volunteers can be done with normal CiviCRM functionality. So they are not really maintaining it.